# calling a servlet from another application

Tags: java, servlets

I have two applications...for simplicity im giving there names **XXX** and **YYY**.

My requirement is to run **XXX** application using itzz war file named XXX.war and I need to call a servlet named myservlet of **YYY** application.

But now what I'm getting is an url like this(`http://localhost:8080/XXX`) . I have gone through this url that time I'm getting a error message resource not found.

I checked by adding `/myservlet` at the end of url. That time it works fine and perfect.

Really what I need is a url like this 
(`http://localhost:8080/XXX/mysevlet`)

The contact path I given in my **XXX** application is `/myservlet`.

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense. Please elaborate the concrete functional requirement in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your web.xml is incorrectly configured. Can you post your web.xml 
code here. BlausC is correct, without seeing the descriptor file, to anything
or diagnose is not fruitful. Post your web.xml
Thanks,
Ben